# Sporadic Ajax Status response 502, 504, or 0 in a CORRECT url

Tags: javascript, ajax, status

I have a script that triggers an Ajax call to the server every minute. I just do it to see who is online; typically the post page registers a time stamp for the user (but that is off topic).

It works fine but I have a VERY STRANGE situation: Approximately every 70 calls I get an Ajax Status of 502, 504, or 0. All other Ajax calls work fine! *(readyState == 4 and status == 200)*

**0  ->     ?????? 

502  -> Bad Gateway

504  -> Gateway Timeout**

This is plan JS. Do you know what can cause this? Again, the URL is "well formed", no cross domain calls, and most of the calls work fine.

I'd really appreciate your opinion.

Danny Bullo

Comment: Server or network related issue. Not javascript related.

Comment: So what is in a server logs?

Comment: it is a shared hosting (bluehost). I will check the logs but probably it won't say much.

Comment: Yes...log shows all requests with status response = 200....